# Declaring global functions in a TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a set of plain JS functions defined in my `index.html` function. I would like to declare those functions to be able to use them in TypeScript files. This is what I do:

```
declare function getHtmlBasePath(): String;
declare function fbFetchedLoginStatus(): boolean;
declare function getFbAccessToken(): String;
declare function setFbAccessToken(token: String);
```

However, to avoid declaring those files in every TypeScript file where they are used, I would like to define them in a separate file and import that file wherever I want. This way, I void duplicate declaration and I also get the support of the IDE if I want to do refactoring later. However, by the time I define those declarations in a TypeScript file and import them, the TypeScript compiler will assume this is a module that actually has to be imported, while it is simply a declaration file (more like a header file for an external library in C/C++).

Is there a way to have a certain TypeScript serves no purpose other than set of a declaration, i.e. when you import it, TypeScript compiler doesn't generate `require` statements?

Answer (score 3):

Export the function definition in a separate file using `export` keyword:

```
export function getHtmlBasePath(): String {
    // your code
}
```

TO use the function in any other typescript file, just import the function using the `import` keyword.

```
import {getHtmlBasePath} from 'filename';
```

`filename` is the name of the file where the function definition is written. After import the function you ca use the function as any other normal function.

Comment: This is what I did actually, but it TypeScript compiler ended up treating the function declaration as a function and appended the module name to the name of the function, when what I wanted is actually just a way for TypeScript compiler to recognize that this function is defined globally.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler is smart enough not to transform those declarations into `require` statements. In fact, none of them will end up in your compiled JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as I see a dependency being added for the `globals` module.