# add a function to the global namespace in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, import, global-variables

Is it possible to add a function to the global namespace in TypeScript?

I have a function that I use so ubiquitously that is very much tied to a certain programming style that I don't want have an import in every file that uses it.

I thought I was close by defining this function in a file without any exports. The compiler did not complain, but at runtime the function was not found.

Comment: Does one of these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736473/how-to-define-global-function-in-typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971729/declaring-global-functions-in-a-typescript-module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652241/define-global-function-in-module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234400/typescript-global-function ?

Comment: The first one did. I did a bad job in searching for an answer first. Thanks